# Is it ok to have overriden getters of an Objective-C class be static?

Tags: objective-c

I have some existing code I'm modifying from another developer.  They have a static NSString declared as follows...

```
static NSString *myStaticString;
```

This string should be initialized before use.  What I'm looking to do is have a property method overriden which will ensure the variable is set.  Here's what my suggested layout would look like...

```
static NSString *myStaticString;

@interface MyClass ()
@property (readonly) NSString   *myProperty;
@end

@implementation MyClass
+(NSString *)myProperty
{
    if (!myStaticString)
      myStaticString = [@"My string value!" retain];

    return myStaticString;
}
@end
```

The new thing for me here is I've never declared a getter as a static method and to be honest I don't know if that is a good idea or not.

Comment: Is that a singleton? Have you considered using a static method variable? Have you considered using `dispatch_once`?

Comment: @Sulthan no I hadn't considered using dispatch_once but someone else suggested an answer using that.  Seems to fit my needs perfectly so I think I will be making use of it.  Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as a static method in Objective-C. The method you posted is a *class method*, which is dispatched dynamically the same way an instance method is dispatched. A class method can't be a property of an object.

Comment: @jlehr didn't realize that about static/class methods.  Good to know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to the question (and I paraphrase) "is it ok to have getters return a pointer to a static?" the answer is yes, it is.

The issue here is, though, that getters are instance methods, and you've defined a class method. So you'll end up with a confusing combination of your explicitly defined class method that happens to bear the same name of an automatically synthesized getter instance method (and, worse, that synthesized getter instance method will just be returning a pointer to some automatically synthesized ivar, which is obviously not what you intended). Bottom line, you are not overriding the getter like you obviously thought you were.

As bbum pointed out, you can easily remedy this by defining this explicitly declared method as an instance method. By doing that, you will thereby be overriding the getter, accomplishing what you probably intended.

Personally, since there's nothing here that requires an instance method, I might be inclined to just retire the property altogether and have the class method return a pointer to the string referenced by your static variable. In that case, I'd suggest one of two approaches:

1. If the string is truly a constant, then I might do something like:

   ```
   // MyClass.h

   @interface MyClass : NSObject

   + (NSString *)someString;

   @end
   ```

   and

   ```
   // MyClass.m

   #import "MyClass.h"

   static NSString * const kSomeInternalConstant = @"my string";

   @implementation MyClass

   + (NSString *)someString
   {
       return kSomeInternalConstant;
   }

   @end
   ```
2. If the string is defined at runtime, but does not change while the app is running, then I'd replace the `MyClass.m` with:

   ```
   // MyClass.m

   #import "MyClass.h"

   @implementation MyClass

   + (NSString *)someString
   {
       static NSString *someInternalString = nil;

       static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
       dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
           someInternalString = ...  // set it to be whatever you want
       });

       return someInternalString;
   }

   @end
   ```

Clearly, replace these variable names with something more logical, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: this is great thanks.  I hadn't considered using dispatch_once since I haven't used GCD too much.  Seems to work great for my purposes.

Comment: A better answer, but eliminates the `@property` declaration.  Nothing wrong with that, but no longer an instance method.

Comment: @bbum Agreed. I could have gone either way on this: Your answer, to fix the property's getter by changing it to an instance method, was perfectly valid (though misinterpreted) and more directly answered "the letter" of the question. I tried to answer "the spirit" of the question: The desired functionality is consistent with a class method (and he declared it as such), so I applied Ockham's Razor and got rid of the redundant property as it doesn't feel like a compelling use of property, anyway. But your answer is perfectly valid (and was too quickly criticized, IMHO).

Comment: @Rob Answer undeleted w/some clarification.  This answer is likely inline w/OP's desires, but subclassing may be in play, too.

Comment: @Rob yep basically you're answer gave me a good perspective.  Properties are not necessary and the code seems more readable as a result.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for the class-level equivalent of @property, then the answer is "there's no such thing". But remember, @property is only syntactic sugar, anyway; it just creates appropriately-named object methods.

You still can use class methods that access static variables which have only a slightly different syntax.

Here's thread safe example:

```
// Foo.h
@interface Foo {
}

+(NSDictionary*) dictionary;

// Foo.m
+(NSDictionary*) dictionary
{
  static NSDictionary* fooDict = nil;

  static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

  dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        // create dict
    });

  return fooDict;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need it to be an instance method:

```
-(NSString *)myProperty
{
    if (!myStaticString)
      myStaticString = [@"My string value!" retain];

    return myStaticString;
}
```

And, yes, that is fine.

---

• The `retain` is odd;  don't need it, doesn't hurt.  Best turn on ARC and be done with it.

• I'd move the static into the method or, if it never changes, just return `@"My string value!"` directly.

• This is not an uncommon pattern;  this class may return a default, static, value and subclasses might override to return a different value, as necessary.

• When initializing a static, use `dispatch_once`.  In this case, it doesn't matter as it is an assignment of a static constant string.  But, like the `retain`, best to follow convention (i.e. eliminate the `retain`, use `dispatch_once` or just return the value directly).

Comment: Not sure I get your answer @bbum (that's a first time :P) What if the string is class specific? Just a method that returns some class specific string? And, why is the string literal retained? :D

Comment: @nikans It is if there is an @property declaration....  Though I'd move the static declaration into the method and use `dispatch_once()`.

Comment: @ValentinRadu *technically* `retain`ing the string literally is correct.  By convention, no one ever does it and it just doesn't matter.  Having a class return a static in an instance method is fine, especially if it is a default value that is overridden in subclasses.